# CSS skeleton animation for div elements

Tags: html, css

When using svg elements we can create and animate the ghost:

```html
<svg role="img" aria-labelledby="Loading interface..." viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><title>Loading interface...</title><rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" clip-path="url(#lk4fia56qdl)" style="fill: url(&quot;#mdbp2uer6wl&quot;);"></rect><defs><clipPath id="lk4fia56qdl"><rect x="0" y="160" rx="0" ry="0" width="25" height="40"></rect><rect x="30" y="145" rx="0" ry="0" width="25" height="55"></rect><rect x="60" y="126" rx="0" ry="0" width="25" height="74"></rect><rect x="90" y="80" rx="0" ry="0" width="25" height="120"></rect><rect x="120" y="142" rx="0" ry="0" width="25" height="58"></rect></clipPath><linearGradient id="mdbp2uer6wl"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f0f0f0" stop-opacity="1"><animate attributeName="offset" values="-3; 1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></stop><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#e0e0e0" stop-opacity="1"><animate attributeName="offset" values="-2; 2" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f0f0f0" stop-opacity="1"><animate attributeName="offset" values="-1; 3" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate></stop></linearGradient></defs></svg>
```

Is there any way to get the same or a similar animation by using `div` elements?

```
<section class="bars" style="display: flex">
 <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
 <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
 <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
 <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [`background-attachement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) and slide a gradient :

example

```css
.bars {
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vh;
  margin: 15vh auto auto;
}

.bars>div {
  margin: 0 2vh;
  flex: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f0f0f0, #e0e0e0, #f0f0f0) 0 0/ 100vh 100% fixed;
  animation: bgslide 6s infinite linear
}

@keyframes bgslide {
  to {
    background-position: 100vw 0
  }
}

.bars :first-child {
  margin-top: 35vh;
}

.bars :nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 25vh;
}

.bars :nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 8vh;
}

.bars :last-child {
  margin-top: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="bars">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

*demo is using `background-attachement:fixed` and viewports units to scale*

---

[`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) works too :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: white
}

body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: gray;
  clip-path: polygon(2% 100%, 2% 60%, 15% 60%, 15% 100%, 20% 100%, 20% 37%, 35% 37%, 35% 100%, 40% 100%, 40% 9%, 60% 9%, 60% 100%, 65% 100%, 65% 26%, 80% 26%, 80% 100%, 85% 100%, 85% 50%, 100% 50%, 98% 50%, 98% 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f0f0f0, #e0e0e0, #f0f0f0) 0 0/ 100vh 100% fixed;
  animation: bgslide 6s infinite linear
}

@keyframes bgslide {
  to {
    background-position: 100vw 0
  }
}
```

here is an online tool to help you create a `clip-path` css rule: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/